# can i list all my data in angular using List

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-list

Can i list all my data using mat-list? I want to create a dialog with container and all my data from `DTO` will show in the list, like in the mat-table we used a datasource to get all data. its that possible? I don't have codes yet.

[image: TRIED IT BUT IT WONT WORK]

Comment: It should be possible, would be able to help you better if you provide the object which you wanna fill in the mat-list.

Comment: `export class DeliveryDTO{
    transactionType: string 
}`
this is the object i wanted to list

Comment: <table>
    <thead style="text-align:center">
        <th>DR Number</th>
        <th>Item Description</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let items of delivery">
      <td>
      <span>{{items.transactionType}}</span>
    </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: i just edit my question i post the picture

Comment: Is this DR Number serial number?